# Asked to Enable Macros In a Workbook Without Them

Tags: excel, vba

The macro copies over the sheets to a newly created workbook, I send this report that is WITHOUT MACROS.

However, my client says she has to open the file to enable macros and then re-save.
She says she has a "file linked to the report," so prob. a program that pulls data from the closed report.
She also sent me a photo of her screen with the little yellow bar prompting her that the file is in protected view.

Is there any reason in my code that explains this situation?

Here is my code:

```
Sub Generate_Position_Report()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual 

Application.Calculate
Do While Application.CalculationState <> xlDone
     DoEvents
Loop

''''''''' Open Previous Report '''''''''
Dim d As Date
d = DateAdd("d", -1, Date)
Dim d3 As Date
d3 = d - 2

Dim prev_file As String
Dim prev_file_exists As String

prev_file = "X:\Risk\Departmental\Reporting\Position Report " & Format(d, "yyyy-mm-dd") & ".xlsx"
prev_file_exists = Dir(prev_file)
    
    If prev_file_exists <> "" Then
        Workbooks.Open Filename:="X:\Risk\Departmental\Reporting\Position Report " & Format(d, "yyyy-mm-dd") & ".xlsx"
    Else
        Workbooks.Open Filename:="X:\Risk\Departmental\Reporting\Position Report " & Format(d3, "yyyy-mm-dd") & ".xlsx"
    End If

ThisWorkbook.Activate

''''''''' Variables '''''''''
sim_date = Range("SIM_DATE").Value
main_analysis_name = Range("MAIN_ANALYSIS_NAME").Value
secondary_analysis_name = Range("SECONDARY_ANALYSIS_NAME").Value
previous_workday = Range("PREVIOUS_WORKDAY").Value
t_minus_2_workday = Range("T_MINUS_2_WORKDAY").Value
previous_day_quotes = Range("PREVIOUS_DAY_QUOTES").Value
t_minus_2_quotes = Range("T_MINUS_2_DAY_QUOTES").Value
price_curves_analysis = Range("PRICE_CURVES_ANALYSIS").Value
previous_analysis_date = Range("PREVIOUS_ANALYSIS_DATE").Value
previous_analysis_name = Range("PREVIOUS_ANALYSIS_NAME").Value
col_shift = Range("COL_SHIFT").Value

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

''''''''' Recalculate Data '''''''''
Application.Calculate
Do While Application.CalculationState <> xlDone
     DoEvents
Loop

'''''''''' Save the Template ''''''''''
'good practice to turn things back on for the template'
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

ThisWorkbook.Save

'we need to turn them off again to finalize the report'
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'''''''''' Copy/Paste Values ''''''''''
'we need to copy and paste values for all the worksheets'
For Each ws In Worksheets
    Sheets(ws.Name).Activate
    Sheets(ws.Name).Cells.Copy
    Sheets(ws.Name).Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Sheets(ws.Name).Cells(1, 1).Select  
Next

'''''''''' Create Fresh Copy Without Macros ''''''''''
ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Copy
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="X:\Risk\Departmental\Reporting\Position Report (TEST) " & Format(d + 1, "yyyy-mm-dd") & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=51

'physically breaking links'
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Application.ActiveWorkbook
If Not IsEmpty(wb.LinkSources(xlExcelLinks)) Then
    For Each link In wb.LinkSources(xlExcelLinks)
        wb.BreakLink link, xlLinkTypeExcelLinks
    Next link
End If

'''''''''' Activate/Hide/Delete Tabs ''''''''''
Worksheets("Control").Visible = False
Worksheets("Reference").Visible = False
Worksheets("HERITAGE Summary").Activate

'turning back on some features for the active/report'
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

ActiveWorkbook.Save 'saving the report'
Workbooks(2).Close 'closes the prev. file'
ThisWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False 'closes the template'

End Sub
```

Comment: Um... Your code is a macro. It requires macros enabled in order to be run.

Comment: Has your client saved the file to a Trusted Location? Was the file downloaded, it may need to be unprotected in file explorer. As per Ken what are the client's macro settings in the Trust Center?

Comment: Files from an email typically open in "Protected view" - they must be unprotected before any macros in them can be run.  Details here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/what-is-protected-view-d6f09ac7-e6b9-4495-8e43-2bbcdbcb6653?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us

Comment: The purpose of protected view is to protect the user's PC from the actions of unwanted macros. Don't advise her to disable such protection. If you can't send her a workbook in xlsx format (without code) she should change her work flow to save the file first. Consider providing her with a file containing the code which she enables once and send her xlsx workbooks with data only thereafter. Code can also be sent in TXT format and easily imported into an xlsx workbook.